# Running g++ compiled files withoud cmd on windows

Tags: c++, g++

I am new to using g++ compiler and i compiled an .exe file,i know that i can run with command line,but is it possible to run .exe file by just clicking on it.I tried it and i get an error(Entry point not found).

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).  Then you can run your `exe` from command line.  Or make a shell script that runs your program into an icon to click.